# Background Image Rotator with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a website that the background image will fade from one to another, I have it setup and working about 98%. There is just one little problem. When it first loads and does it's first fade it fades to white and then to the image, instead of fading straight into the next image. After that it work beautifully. This is using jQuery 1.9 and I have jQuery noConflict on since the previous developer coded the sites menu using MooTools.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="js/jquery.js">
  </script>
  <script>
var $s = jQuery.noConflict();

function swapImages(){
  var $sactive = $s('#myGallery .active');
  var $snext = ($s('#myGallery .active').next().length > 0) ? $s('#myGallery .active').next() : $s('#myGallery img:first');

  $snext.fadeIn(1500).addClass('active');
  $sactive.fadeOut(2000, function(){
  });
  $sactive.removeClass('active');
};

$s(document).ready(function(){
  // Run our swapImages() function every 5secs
  setInterval('swapImages()', 5000);

});
</script>
</head>
<style>

 #myGallery{
   position:relative;
   width:100%; /* Set your image width */
   height:auto; /* Set your image height */
 }

 #myGallery img{
   display:none;
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   width: 100%;
   left:0;
 }

 #myGallery img.active{
   display:block;
 }

 .home-page-rotator{
   position:absolute;
   width:100%;
   z-index:-10;
 }
</style>
<body>
<div class="home-page-rotator" id="myGallery">
 <img src="images/1.jpg" class="active" />
 <img src="images/2.jpg" />
 <img src="images/3.jpg" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I took out all the content so you can test if you wanted but the is everything that runs the background rotation and fade. Also I have the CSS in a seperate file but for posting to here I just put it inline so you can see the CSS behind the code. Let me know what I should do to fix this?

Comment: Are you looking to rotate through background-images (as in css) or through img elements (as in DOM elements)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the remove class method to the function call of the fadeout seems to work better for me (at least in Chrome):

```
<script>
    var $s = jQuery.noConflict();

    function swapImages(){
      var $sactive = $s('#myGallery .active');
      var $snext = ($s('#myGallery .active').next().length > 0) ? $s('#myGallery .active').next() : $s('#myGallery img:first');

      $sactive.fadeOut(2000, function(){
          $sactive.removeClass('active');
      });
      $snext.fadeIn(1500).addClass('active');
    };

    $s(document).ready(function(){
      // Run our swapImages() function every 5secs
      setInterval('swapImages()', 5000);

    });
</script>
```

Comment: This one worked for me on Safari, FireFox and Chrome can anyone confirm on IE?

Comment: Yes. It looks good in IE9. I do not have IE8 to test with, but looks OK in the IE8 mode of IE9.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem a while back and I found the easiest solution was to switch from img elements to using two divs and the background-image css url to display your images. I made a simple slider for that a while back. You're welcome to copy whatever you need from it.

[Background slider source](https://github.com/smithcyr/jQuerySlider/blob/master/jQuerySlider.js)

In essence, if you have two divs that are absolutely positioned as the background elements, you can cycle their z-indexes and fade them in and out. Furthermore, you can load the next image in a constructed img element and once it has loaded, change the background-image of the hidden div and fade to it. This means that there is no loading shown and you can fade directly into the slideshow.

Here's some pseudo code below, but it would probably be easier to just look at the real functions in the source.

```
base.next_slide = function () {
    "current slide" = "next slide";
    base.containers[the_shown_container].fadeOut(duration,function () {
      $(this).css({'background-image':'url("' + "Next image url" + '")',
                   "z-index":"-2"});
      base.containers[the_next_container].css("z-index","-1");
      $(this).show();
      the_shown_container = the_next_container;
    });
  };

Plugin.prototype.init = function (base) {
  $('<img/>').attr('src', "Next image url").load(function() {
    base.containers[the_next_container].css('background-image', 'url(' + "Next image url" + ')');
    if ("there's only one image in the slider"){
      base.containers[the_shown_container].fadeOut(duration,function () {
        $(this).css("z-index","-2");
        base.containers[the_next_container].css("z-index","-1");
      });
      return;
    }
    base.next_slide();
    setInterval(base.next_slide ,base.o.interval);
  });
};
```